# how to get value of id in html option form control?

Tags: jquery, html

my data list contain id and groupName.
id as 1,2,3,4,5
groupName as Friend,family,school,college,sivagiri.

i am displaying the groupname, user select the group name means , i want to get id for the select group.

my code is :

```
          <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 5%">
            <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"
                style="color: #ffcc33"></i></span> <input class="form-control"
                placeholder="Select Group" id="acqGroup" list="group" />
            <datalist id="group">
            </datalist>

        </div>
```

and jsp code:

```
                            $.each(modelMap.distAcqGroupList, function(index, groupBO) {
                                $("#group").append($("<option></option>").text(groupBO.groupName));

                            });
```

now the data list is loading perfectly , and selected value is displayed but i want to get an id for selected value. i try as

```
                 $("#acqGroup").blur(function() {           
                        var group = $("#acquaintanceGroup").val();
                        alert(group);

                    });
```

it display only select item text, i want the id, please help me

Comment: how are you supposed to get an id if you didn't have added it in the `option` element ? Also, please don't use id, but `value` to set/get a value of a selected option element.

Comment: i can't understand karel what u say?

Comment: `.append($("<option></option>")` <-- there is no `id`, so when you pick an id, you get an empty string. So give it an id to get non-empty strings. But i advise to use `value` as attribute. Please check [`<option>` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes). And get the value of the selected item instead of id. Unless it's necessary to use id for selecting the selected option element ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#acquaintanceGroup :selected").attr('id');
```

will give you the `id` of selected element.
As [**@KarelG**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360614/how-to-get-value-of-id-in-html-option-form-control/23360654#comment35778975_23360614) have pointed out, you should first add `id` to `option` elements

Answer (score 0):

how about using this?

```
var group = $("#acquaintanceGroupoption option").filter(":selected").attr('id');
```